# SQL Server Log Databases Starting Up Every Hour

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql

I have been doing an audit of my SQL Server log, as I 'thought' it was locked down but appeared to be open and we were getting a lot of password attempts on the SA account.

After sorting that, I have noticed throughout the day in the ErrorLog I have entries like this

```
2012-04-20 09:45:13.08 spid81      Starting up database 'DatabaseNameOne'.
2012-04-20 09:48:45.23 spid65      Starting up database 'DatabaseNameTwo'.
2012-04-20 09:53:58.16 spid143     Starting up database 'DatabaseNameFour'.
2012-04-20 09:54:28.24 spid151     Starting up database 'DatabaseNameFive'.
2012-04-20 09:54:47.04 spid152     Starting up database 'DatabaseNameSix'.
```

For all the databases on the server. Its doing this more or less every hour? Is that right? I assumed once the database had started thats it unless I restart the SQL service or shut down the server?

Any advice appreciated - Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check to see if [Auto Close](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckwoody/archive/2009/06/24/sql-server-best-practices-autoclose-should-be-off.aspx) is set to true.

If it is this closes the database when the last connection is closed, basically makes it go to sleep. It will fill your log up with those messages if it is left enabled. Best practice, unless needed, is to set it to false for all databases.